# Jest mock only called when default explicitly called

Tags: typescript, jestjs

## Problem

Using `jest` with Typescript, I am trying to mock some dependencies, and I am getting very strange behaviors using different approaches.

When `"esModuleInterop": true` in `tsconfig.json`:

**tmp.ts**

```js
import packageJson from 'package-json';

export async function testFn() {
  return packageJson('test');
}
```

**tmp.test.ts**

```js
import {testFn} from './tmp';
import packageJson from 'package-json';

describe('testFn', () => {

  it('should be able to mock', async () => {
    (packageJson as any).default = jest.fn().mockImplementation(async () => 'hello');

    await testFn();
    expect(packageJson.default).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

The above test fails:

```
Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

## Workaround

I found two ways to fix the problem:

- Replacing `return packageJson('test');` with `return packageJson.default('test');` in `tmp.ts` fixes the problem.
- Setting `"esModuleInterop": false` in `tsconfig.json`

However, I am not satisfied with neither of those solutions.

## Question

I logged `packageJson` in `tmp.ts`:

```
[AsyncFunction: packageJson] {
  default: [Circular],
  PackageNotFoundError: [Function: PackageNotFoundError],
  VersionNotFoundError: [Function: VersionNotFoundError]
}
```

Calling both `packageJson(...)` and `packageJson.default(...)` produces the same result when not mocked (it returns the info of the given Npm package).

I tried an import variant in `tmp.test.ts` but get the same error:

```
import * as packageJson from 'package-json';
```

I also tried another mock syntax:

```
jest.mock('package-json', () => ({
  default: jest.fn().mockImplementation(async () => 'hello'),
}));
```

But then get `Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function`.